# Change style of tooltip CSS bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I want to change the style of tooltip : background color to white (see picture), for that I used css this code to do it:

html code:

```
<th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">Test <sup><img src="assets/icons/help.png" data-toggle="tooltip" title="test test" data-flow="bottom"></sup></th>
```

CSS code :

```
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #16181b;
  width:100%;
}
[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: .9em;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but it does not apply, any help please

What I have :
[image]

what I want :

[image]

Now I can change background color :

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #00000040;
}
```

But the tooltip is under border of cell like this :
[image]
How can I show dehor??

Comment: Please check if all the necessary bootstrap files are correctly included. For this to work, you'll specifically need the JS files as well -- check the complete list [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn).

Comment: I used angular, how can I add JS file in the component ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular I'm afraid, you might have to look for Bootstrap documentation specific to Angular.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to see that

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Use the depp selector for angular

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-inner {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #00000040;
  padding: 15px;
}

::ng-deep.tooltip-arrow {
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px;
}
```